# if without condition?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, if-statement

I just found this "C++" today and i cannot make sense of it:

> `if(array[i][j]) {--i;--j;}`

can anyone explains to me how this work? I just don't get it. What is the condition here? It seems like it would be true every time, but when i got rid of the IF (so only this `{--i;--j;}` left.) it doesn't work the same.

I'm quite new to C++ so go easy with the explanations! :)

Thanks!

Comment: So it was you who introduced the trend for `if (val != 0){...}` !

Comment: On a related note, it is perfectly valid to say `boolean b = whatever(); if (b) { ... } else { ... }`, because `if` does not expect a *condition*, but rather a *boolean expression*, and one of the simplest boolean expressions is the name of a boolean variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

assuming array is an array of int (or other integral types) the condition will be false if and only if `array[i][j] == 0`

Answer (score 21):

In C++, a non-zero value can be used to indicate 'success' in a conditional statement.

This is from C99, section 6.8.4.1:

> The `if` Statement
>
> 2 In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.

From C++03, section 6.4

> 4 The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a statement other than a switch statement is the value of the declared variable implicitly converted to type bool. If that conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed. The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a switch statement is the value of the declared variable if it has integral or enumeration type, or of that variable implicitly con- verted to integral or enumeration type otherwise. The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the expression, implicitly converted to bool for statements other than switch; if that conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed. The value of the condition will be referred to as simply “the condi- tion” where the usage is unambiguous.

And boolean conversion is defined in 6.3.1.2

> 6.3.1.2 Boolean type
>
> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

And `int` is a scalar type. I assume that's what your array is filled with as you can use unary `++` and `--` on them.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` is gets a `true` if `array[i][j]` gets `true` when cast to a `bool`. If `array` has e.g. `float` or `int`values, anything not equal to `0` will be cast to `true`. The situation could be different for user-defined types.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement requires a boolean value in its parentheses.  So it will try to explicitly cast whatever your expression is into a boolean.  For integers and pointers, for example, a non-zero value will be true and a zero value will be false.

So if your expression (array[i][j]) can be cast to true then the condition will be true.

Comment: I think you meant to say "So it will try to _implicitly_ cast whatever your expression is into a boolean"

Answer (score 0):

the "condition" is a `bool` expression. In C++, `int` can be implicitly cast to `bool`. (where 0 = false, and everything else is true).

Comment: 0 = false, every other value = true (not just 1).

Comment: ack! thank you; updated my answer. i was thinking the other way around (casting from bool -> int means true = 1).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to understand if I rewrite your code the following way:

```
if((array[i][j])==true)
{
    --i;
    --j;
}
```

So that means, the if condition actually checks whether your array row and column value is boolean true. Then it will go inside your if-block and decrement i and j value, that means it will shift to the previous row and previous column of your array.

Of course, you need to cast the data-type of your array value into boolean prior to implementing this.